# Move /#/data/app to external SD

Tags: external-sd, apk, folder-organizer

Folks I've rooted my device and installed Directory Bind. I'm not sure if I can move the /#/data/app folder to an external SD. There I have all my .apk files. But I seem unable to find this folder when I look for it in Directory Bind. I'm confused about it. I could sucessfully move the data files but not the .apks what am I missing?

Comment: try using a different file explorer other then the default one.

Comment: When you use directory bind does it ask for root?

Comment: It does ask for root. Hence it would not be able to access the sudo binary right?

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by the # in your path?

What you should do is this, Get Android SDK (http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) if you haven't got it already, then enable debugging mode on your phone and connect your phone to your pc with usb cable.

In the file explorer lookup the symlink to your external sdcard. its probably /extSdCard or /external_sd

Now open up an terminal window and enter:

```
adb root
adb remount
adb shell busybox mv -f /data/app /extSdCard/
```

it would move the app folder to your external sdcards root dir.

Or download terminal emulator app and enter:

```
su
busybox mv -f /data/app /extSdCard/
```

This should work, if not let me know

Comment: Hi, the # stands for the "/" folder. File system base.

Comment: so that's a useless addition, since / is already the root, no /#/ is needed. Anyways, try it pls

Comment: I also should add it that even if you move that folder, you can not use the apps within `/data/app` from external sdcard.